# How to correctly append values of a dictionary to an empty dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am trying to create a dataframe that will have rows added to it in a for loop. So I decided to first create an empty version of the dataframe, and then create a dictionary for a new row and append that dictionary to the dataframe in each iteration of the loop. The problem is that the values in the dataframe do not properly match the values that were in the dictionary:

I create an empty dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({"a":[], "b":[], "c":[]})
```

I would then create a dictionary and append it to the dataframe like:

```
dict = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":True}
df = df.append(dict, ignore_index=True)
```

The problem is that instead of getting `a=1, b=1, c=True` the dataframe has `a=1.0, b=1.0, c=1.0`

So how can I make the columns of a and b integers, and the column of c a boolean value?

Comment: what you want your final df should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not convert `dictionary` to `dataframe` in the first line. Better convert it at last

```py
import pandas
dicts = {"a":[], "b":[], "c":[]} #do not convert dict to df
new_dict = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":True}

for k,v in new_dict.items():
  dicts[k].append(new_dict[k])

df = pd.DataFrame(dicts)
```

Output:

```
df

    a   b   c
0   1   2   True
```